# make single-page web app perform faster

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a single-page web app (actually, its PhoneGap).

It has a lot of different 'pages' or screens - about 30 now.

The issue is if each page has loaded some content (complex element lists, sometimes hundreds of items long), the app starts to bog down and become very slow, as all the html is present, even if hidden.

I was thinking that if between pages changes i store the HTML for the content in a variable, to be called and put back in the DOM when a user wants to go back to that page, will this make other pages faster than leaving everything in the DOM? So basically I only have 1 full page in the html at a time.

Just wanted to ask before i spent time doing it! any other links for fast web apps would be appreciated too

Comment: when you have multiple pages, instead of hide and show, Why can't you try to replace the content ?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to remove the useless DOMs to release the memory.

Actually, when you realize your page (or App) is going slower and slower, you should pay attention on the memory.

Remove all useless DOMs would be a smart choice on your case. Next time, you need to show it again, you can re-initialize it.

Sometimes, you may also need to remove useless js objects, unbind events, etc.